# Fabricjs Text object fontSize units

Tags: fabricjs

after some digging in the code, i realized that the fontSize of fabricjs Text object is being measured in PIXELS. in my projects, sometime i need to use points instead of pixels.

i have found only one place in the code when the units being specified , this snippet:

```
    /**
 * @private
 * @method _getFontDeclaration
 */
_getFontDeclaration: function() {
  return [
    this.fontStyle,
    this.fontWeight,
    this.fontSize + 'px',
    (fabric.isLikelyNode ? ('"' + this.fontFamily + '"') : this.fontFamily)
  ].join(' ');
}
```

will i break dependencies (any metric specific calculations based on this field) if i will just replace '`px`' with '`pt`'   ???

ps: there is no information within documentation about fontSize units/metrics of the **fabric.Text** object, it will nice to add it to save time to others...

Comment: I updated docs to specify "px" as units of fontSize. You're right that pt's (or any other non-px units) are not supported. You could work around it by doing transformation on an application level.

Answer (score 5):

Recently a "parseUnit" method has been added.

You can define your setFontSize function as follow:

```
fabric.Text.prototype.setFontSize = function(size) {
  this.fontSize = fabric.util.parseUnit(size);
  return this;
}
```

In fabricjs DPI is set to 96 ( can be changed ) and 'pt'is converted in this way:

```
return number * fabric.DPI / 72
```

In this way you can use 'mm', 'cm', 'in', 'pt', 'pc', 'em'